# Code breaks unless I include the '.js' file extension in the require statement. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

At the top of my file, I have this line:

```
const Block = require('./block');
```

Inside block.js, I export the Block class like so:

```
module.exports = Block;
```

Normally, everything works. But now for some reason, everything is turning up undefined unless I also include the .js file extension like so:

```
const Block = require('./block.js');
```

If I include that, then everything works.

For reference, the require is happening inside a Jest test file and I'm using Node 8.9.4.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue?

Comment: Have you tried : `require('./Block')`?

Comment: Perhaps you have added another file with the same name but different extension in that location. You should always use the full name and extension nonetheless.

Comment: @PredatorIWD Ugh!!! Yes, there was an additional blank _block_ file in the same directory without an extension. I have no idea how it got there. Thanks.

Comment: Try... module.exports.Block = () => { return 0; // value } and normally ./block with out .js. as long as the file you are requiring is .js file, then require should know.